# How acceptable is to use Cariño for non-relatives?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, expresiones

I usually greet my friends in many different ways, like *`Hola, guapa / bonita / amiga / etc.`*

Sometimes with really close friends I would also use *`Hola, princesa!`* in a more perky way.

But is it OK to use **cariño** for non-family members, even if those people are very good and close friends to you? I'm not really sure how much affection is applied by this word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mexico is not a word a man would use for anybody but a spouse or daughter, not even a son.
For women is different, they would use it way more often and also depends on the socioeconomic level (amongst high-middle class it would be acceptable) (copy & pasted from above)

Answer (score 5):

it depends also on the context, for example in Spain between friends, or in a relaxed environment,  is OK and pretty common, but in a (formal) work environment it can be seen as a sexist comment, pretty much like your boss saying "honey" or "princess" to a girl in a meeting.

Comment: I would not say it's pretty common to say cariño to friends at least not in the east side of Spain. You usually say that to your partner (or son/daughter if you are a mother).

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it depends a lot on the country and even region.

In some places I have seen "cariño" used among close frinds, mostly women. Also I have it seen used to mark distance (a superior woman calling an inferior "cariño" as a sign of superiority like the one has over her children).

Comment: De la misma manera es usado en cuba

Answer (score 2):

It depends highly on

- Country (e.g. in Chile it would be acceptable, in Argentina the word is not very much used in this sense)
- Socioeconomic level (amongst high-middle class it would be acceptable)
- Sexism awareness

So I'd ask directly if the use would be OK among your group.